# Does Boost::Mpi support parallel IO

Tags: c++, boost, parallel-processing, mpi, boost-mpl

Does Boost::Mpi support Parallel I/O? I cannot find any information about it and of course the boost documentation (even about the linker flags) is completly out of date ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Boost::MPI only supports functionality up to MPI 1.1 (and [not all of that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html#mpi.c_mapping)), and MPI-IO was part of MPI 2.0.  It's a shame that the Boost::MPI stuff is so out of date, because it's amongst the best C++ interfaces to MPI out there.

Comment: I think the MPI C++ syntax was up to MPI 2.1 before they declared it deprecated?

Comment: @pyCthon, MPI C++ and `Boost.MPI` are two _distinct_ C++ bindings to MPI.

Comment: @HristoIliev i just thought it was interesting that boost is behind the actually MPI C++ binding, would you like me to reword my original comment

Comment: @pyCthon, I'm not a native English speaker, so I've got the impression that your comment addresses the MPI version in the answer. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @HristoIliev I worded my thoughts poorly as well.